# Send a form without using endpoint

Tags: javascript

in order to use this npm package, i need an api endpoint, but what if i want to send this with smtp?

I do not have experience with this kind of package, so i will appreciate your help!

The package is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@betahuhn/feedback-js

my actual code so far:

```
const options = {
      id: 'feedback', // id to identify the form on the backend
      endpoint: baseUrl, // enpoint of your backend to handle the submission
      emailField: true, // show email input field, default: false
      btnTitle: 'Feedback', // title of button
      title: 'Company Feedback', // text at the top
      contactText: 'Or send an email!', // text for other contact option
      contactLink: Contact, // link for other contact option
      typeMessage: 'What feedback do you have?', // message for selecting feedback type
      success: 'Thanks! ', // message displayed on successfull submission
      failedTitle: 'Oops, an error ocurred!', // title displayed on error
      failedMessage: 'Please try again. If this keeps happening, try to send an email instead.', // default error message if backend doesn't return one
      position: 'right', // position of button left/right
      primary: 'rgb(53, 222, 118)', // primary color
      background: '#fff', // background color
      color: '#000' // font color
    }
    console.log(Contact);
    console.log(baseUrl);
      new Feedback(options).attach();

  })
```

how can i send this in the simpliest ways possible?

Comment: SMTP (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol) is, as the name states, an emailing protocol, which you need a backend to send requests on, unless you want to want to send your email account's private key out to the world. So just make a backend with `express` that listens for whatever endpoint you want, and use `nodemailer` to send emails with your email credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an endpoint because a code has to process your form, an HTML form is just a static thing that's only obligated to deliver data to some script.

If you don't want to spend your time on writing an API endpoint you can try form endpoint services like [formcarry](https://formcarry.com) which allows you to collect submissions without any back-end code

If you want to write your own endpoint, then you can follow this detailed [blog post](https://formcarry.com/blog/how-to-create-a-html-contact-form-with-file-upload/)